# PowerShell AD script not working

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For some reason everything works except the homeDirectory. For that everything is blank..The AD actually has values for these fields but this script isn't displaying anything for that attribute. Any ideas?

```
  $objSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
  $objSearch.PageSize = 15000 
  $objSearch.Filter = $ObjFilter 
  $objSearch.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$dn" 
  $AllObj = $objSearch.FindAll() 
foreach ($Obj in $AllObj) 
      { $objItemS = $Obj.Properties 
             $Ssamaccountname = $objItemS.samaccountname 
             $SsamaccountnameGN = $objItemS.givenname 
             $SsamaccountnameSN = $objItemS.sn 
             $SsamaccountnameEN = $objItemS.mail
             $SsamaccountnameLS = $objItemS.homeDirectory
             "$Ssamaccountname`t$SsamaccountnameGN`t$SsamaccountnameSN`t$SsamaccountnameEN`t$SsamaccountnameLS" | Out-File $UserInfoFile -encoding ASCII -append 
      } # End of foreach
   } # End of ForEach-Object
```

Comment: NOt that this is necessarily wrong, but is there a reason you are using the full blown .NET class for this instead of say AD tools, or Quest AD tools? Makes these sorts of things way easier and a one-liner

Comment: I just found "ad info" which is free but buggy. It might do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not attached to using the .NET I really like [Quest Active Directory cmdlets](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx)

Your command would then be:

```
get-qadUser <UserName or another unique attribute> | Format-List <Attributes> | Out-File MyTextFile.txt
```

To get a list of possible attributes, you can:

```
get-qaduser UserName -includeAllAttribute | fl * | Out-File C:\AllAttributes.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you retry adding this line before the `FindAll`:

```
$objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homeDirectory");
```

Generaly speaking it's better to add to the search each attribute you want to retreive.

Comment: I tried what you said and I got an empty results. So now the others don't show either with your change. I then tried adding the $objSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add() line for sn, mail, givenname along with homeDirectory and then the other attributes beside homeDirectory showed like before. Still the homeDirectory doesn't show.

Comment: Just for your information in the underlaying LDAP part it's safe to give all the attributes you need.